# How to conditional logic based on current URL

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an if statement to serve different scripts based on the current `URL` that the user is on.

this is what I came up with so far, but it seems to not work, thanks

```php
// url to show script A
$url_1 = 'https://www.example.com' ;

// url to serve script
$url_2 = 'htpps://www.example.com/page-to-run-script/';

$request_uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$is_page = strpos($request_uri, '/page-to-run-script/');

if ($is_page == true) {
    // run script A...
} else {
    // run script B...
}
```

Comment: Ok... so what is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: RED BOX FROM THE MANUAL: Warning

This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: how can I target those url's to serve different content or scripts ? because for some reason this is not working. maybe there is a better way

Comment: Surely that shouls be `if ($is_page === FALSE) {`

Comment: $url_2 has a typo.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks I will check this out. is there another method of doing this

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like that :

```
$main_url= parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$main_url_segment= explode('/', $main_url);
$url_2= $main_url_segment[2];
$is_page ="page-to-run-script";
if($is_page == $url2){
   // run script A...
} else {
   // run script B...
}
```

Comment: @Osh It's not my answer, I just edited it to fix the formatting.

Comment: ohh thanks. I think I found a fix how should I post it ?
its [here](https://pastebin.com/WnyUhYGy)
was following this stack answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix to my problem thanks to all,
next stage is to make it as a function that takes in an `array` of `url's`.

```php
        // get user url
        $current_user_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

        //list of url's
        $is_page ="https://www.example.com/page-to-run-script";
        $is_category = "https://www.example.com/category";
        $is_home = "https://www.example.com";

        //check if user is in this page
        if ($is_page == $current_user_url || $is_home == $current_user_url) {
            // run script A...
        } elseif ($is_category == $current_user_url) {
            // run script B...
        }
```